# Mismatch in colorbar values on a plot using Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am generating a density plot using three arrays:`x`,`y`, and `z`. However, the values on the colorbar do not correspond to the arrays. For instance, when `x=1`, `y=0.1`, `z=1` which means that the color should be dark red, not yellow according to the colorbar. How do I fix this mismatch?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np

x=np.array([1., 3., 4., 5., 1., 3., 4., 5., 1., 3., 4., 5.])
y=np.array([0.1  , 0.1  , 0.1  , 0.1  , 0.01 , 0.01 , 0.01 , 0.01 , 0.001,
       0.001, 0.001, 0.001])

z=np.array([1, 2, 3 , 4, 5, 6,
       7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12])


plt.imshow(z.reshape(3,4), cmap=cm.hot)
cbar=plt.colorbar()

plt.xlabel("var",size=20)
plt.ylabel("\u03B2",size=20)

y1=np.unique(y)
y1.sort()

x1=np.unique(x)
x1.sort()

yticklabs = y1
xticklabs = x1

plt.xticks(range(4), xticklabs)
plt.yticks(range(3), yticklabs)

plt.show()
```

The current output is

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you assigned wrong y-ticks labels. You can fix it by using this command:

```
plt.yticks(range(3), reversed(yticklabs))
```

[image]